# G-WAN, NodeJS, and Streaming

Tags: node.js, g-wan, http-streaming

Does G-WAN spin up a new NodeJS instance for every user request? *(i.e. if you're using JavaScript for a servlet)* For instance, if 100 users request an action at the same time that's handled by a specific script.

My primary question goes with scripting G-WAN with non-C/C++ languages... can `sendfile` be used from a JavaScript servlet? I want to stream large files to clients which won't be in the `www` folder, but rather from a specified file path on the server. Is this possible? If not, can NodeJS's streaming be used in G-WAN?

Answer (score 1):

> Does G-WAN spin up a new NodeJS instance for every user request?

Unlike other languages (`C/C++, Objective-C/C++, C#, PH7, Java, and Scala`), `Javascript` is not loaded as a module and rather executed as a CGI process, just like `Zend PHP`, or `Perl`.

So, yes, Node.JS will scale poorly unless you use [caching](http://www.gwan.ch/faq#cache) (either G-WAN's or yours).

> can sendfile be used from a JavaScript servlet?

Yes but G-WAN having its own asynchronous machinery it's certainly more efficient to do it "the G-WAN way" (as suggested by Ken).

If you insist for using sendfile() from Javascript then keep in mind that you will have to use it in non-blocking mode and manage the asynchronous events yourself (synchronous calls are BLOCKING the current G-WAN worker thread).

> Can I stream files to clients which won't be in the www folder?

Yes, you can just use a system `symlink` to map a foreign folder to a /www resource - or you can stream contents from within a G-WAN [handler](http://www.gwan.ch/developers#handler) or a [servlet](http://www.gwan.ch/source/stream3.c).

Comment: Thanks, but I can't seem to find any example concerning using `sendfile()` from a JavaScript servlet, I only see C examples

Comment: Most G-WAN examples are in C for a simple reason: CPU/RAM footprint, like G-WAN. Once you are using a runtime like JS or Java you trade simplicity for humungus collections of libraries (many of them redundant with the small-footprint G-WAN API and sometimes conflicting with it). Cohabitation is great for many cases and lets you pick the right tool to do specific tasks. Don't try to do in JS what should be done in C.

Comment: I think a simple **No you can't do that in JS** would have helped... not every programmer is familliar with C, and I'm definitely not gonna learn C for GWAN. Anyway thanks, I guess I'll have to resort to NodeJS's streaming API and NginX

Comment: The answer "No you can't do that in JS" would have been technically wrong - hence a more complex reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can stream content from G-WAN; you can stream content from Node.JS.  Choosing one or the other depends on what other requirements you have since either can support streaming content for the kind of loads you mention (assuming reasonable system resources).  I have a small Node.JS server doing some URL rewrites and reverse-proxy to serve content we license from a 3rd party.  It is entirely separate from the G-WAN server, with HAProxy routing requests to either as appropriate.  From what I've just learned about JavaScript under G-WAN, I wouldn't want to go that route.  From what you are describing, I would stick to a pure G-WAN approach using C (or possibly C++ or one of the others that G-WAN can load as dynamic modules) for writing servlets and handlers.

From personal experience, I recommend C for simplicity, performance and compactness.  C++ is also a good choice.  G-WAN Servlets and Handlers are often quite small snippets of code - especially compared to writing a complete application - so you may be able to make use of C or C++ here even if you are not expert in those languages.

Take a look at the 10-lines-of-C-code implementation of an FLV streamer near the bottom of the [G-WAN User's Manual](http://gwan.com/archives/gwan_linux.pdf).  Other relevant examples are [stream1.c](http://gwan.com/source/stream1.c), [stream2.c](http://gwan.com/source/stream2.c) and [stream3.c](http://gwan.com/source/stream3.c).

To get started, I recommend downloading and installing G-WAN following the [10-second G-WAN installation process](http://gwan.com/download), and then tweaking the servlet sample code to serve some content you have (i.e., change the paths and filenames as needed).

Good luck!

Ken

Comment: **FYI:** G-WAN's JavaScript implementation is handle by NodeJS (you must have node.js installed). So I mean using a JavaScript servlet, can you stream say a file which is not in the `www` folder, but rather somewhere on your disk? I'm trying to build a secure file hosting system

Comment: Wow, that was news to me about G-WAN's JavaScript mechanisms.  I'll adjust my answer a bit.  I still recommend choosing C or at least one of the other languages that enable your code to be dynamically bound to the server at run time.  For serving content not in the www/... path, I'm using symlinks like Gil suggested, and then I have a 404-handler that generates - and serves - missing content dynamically (i.e., the next request for the same bits will find it at the symlink'd location).

Answer (score 0):

There is also other option for using JS by directly embedding VM (Spidermonkey) in servlet.

Comment: But then, will that be usable for Server Programming or just for executing JavaScript snippets of code which wouldn't be really like Server-side Scripting... I am a JavaScript (NodeJS) dev.... no C/C++ background

Comment: @Ohenepee Peps It is possible to expose G-WAN API (or any native functions ) to Your scripts via https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Reference/JS_DefineFunction. So,  yes it would be usable, but requires some C++ work first